# Using python and PyQt4 to scrape data from mlb.com not rendering javascript

Tags: javascript, python, web-scraping, pyqt4

I am trying to render data from a certain page at [MLB.com](http://mlb.mlb.com/stats/sortable.jsp#elem=[object+Object]&tab_level=child&click_text=Sortable+Player+pitching&game_type=%27R%27&season=2015&season_type=ANY&league_code=%27MLB%27&sectionType=sp&statType=pitching&page=1&ts=1450474511146&timeframe=&position=%271%27&playerType=ALL&sortColumn=w&sortOrder=%27desc%27&extended=0) that uses javascript to generate the html for useful data that I would like to scrape. I followed [this tutorial](https://impythonist.wordpress.com/2015/01/06/ultimate-guide-for-scraping-javascript-rendered-web-pages/) on using pyqt4 to render the html, but no javascript is actually rendered and I just get back the same html that I would have gotten before!

Here is my code

```
# Importing
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
from urllib.request import urlopen

# Importing stuff for parsing javascript
import sys
from PyQt4.QtGui import *
from PyQt4.QtCore import *
from PyQt4.QtWebKit import *

#basic function to get scrapy working
url2 = "removed due to size, link is above in post"

class Render(QWebPage):
    def __init__(self, url):
        self.app = QApplication(sys.argv)
        QWebPage.__init__(self)
        self.loadFinished.connect(self._loadFinished)
        self.mainFrame().load(QUrl(url))
        self.app.exec()

    def _loadFinished(self, result):
        self.frame = self.mainFrame()
        self.app.quit()

r = Render(url2)
result = r.frame.toHtml().encode('utf-8')

print(result)
```

Note, that I removed the url in the code above, but it is the same url as the first link in this post.

When I run this code, I get the same html that I would get if I just got the page url with urllib2 and printed the source. What can I do to make this code work as I want it to?

Edit:
Here is the end of my code that I took from the rest of the tutorial that throws an error:

```
r = Render(url2)
result = r.frame.toHtml()
formattedResult = str(result.toAscii())
```

This code throws this error:

```
AttributeError: 'str' object has no attribute 'toAscii'
```

When I don't call the toAscii() and instead just call str(result) I get this error:

```
UnicodeEncodeError: 'ascii' codec can't encode characters in position 21391-21393: ordinal not in range(128)
```

Comment: In addition to what we have already covered, I would add that Selenium is really good for these purposes. (Javascript that is...)

Comment: I have done some research on alternative solutions and I came to a similar conclusion. I will be messing with that soon. Thanks for the help though!

Answer (score 2):

I have found a solution. Instead of doing

```
formattedResult = str(result.toAscii())
```

try with

```
formattedResult = str(result.encode('utf-8'))
```

It worked for me.

Answer (score 1):

The total code at the bottom of the tutorial was wrong. You still need to process the page with lxml:

```
#QString should be converted to string before processed by lxml
formatted_result = str(result.toAscii())

#Next build lxml tree from formatted_result
tree = html.fromstring(formatted_result)

#Now using correct Xpath we are fetching URL of archives
archive_links = tree.xpath('//divass="campaign"]/a/@href')

print archive_links
```

The author simply didn't include the rest of the code at the end.

Comment: The problem that I was having was with the "toAscii()" call. When I include that part, I get an error:  "Attribute Error: Str object has no attribute 'toAscii'. Am I doing something obviously wrong here? Note, I added details in an edit to my origional question.

Comment: I just saw the edit. Try to remove the str() cast and see what happens. What python version are you using?

Comment: I get the same error, python 3 but let me double check Edit: python 3.5.1

Comment: I would check to see if you can pass "result" strait to: tree = html.fromstring(result) You may also try to use str(result).encode('utf8')

Comment: After messing around a bit, I managed to get the variable to print out. But the content of the page that is printed out is escentially the same as it was when I posted the question, where none of the content that I want has been generated. I think the problem lies somewhere in the pyqt4 section.